# Calculating the angle to a location

Tags: ios, objective-c, coordinates

I have an image of an arrow that behaves like a compass to a specific location. Sometimes it works, and other times it's mirrored. So if I was facing east and the location is directly east of me, it should point up, but sometimes it points down.

```
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)heading
{
    // update direction of arrow
    CGFloat degrees = [self p_calculateAngleBetween:_myLocation
                                                and:_otherLocation];
    CGFloat rads = (degrees - heading.trueHeading) * M_PI / 180;


    CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    tr = CGAffineTransformConcat(tr, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rads) );

    [_directionArrowView setTransform:tr];
}

-(CGFloat) p_calculateAngleBetween:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coords0 and:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coords1 {
    double x = 0, y = 0 , deg = 0, deltaLon = 0;

    deltaLon = coords1.longitude - coords0.longitude;
    y = sin(deltaLon) * cos(coords1.latitude);
    x = cos(coords0.latitude) * sin(coords1.latitude) - sin(coords0.latitude) * cos(coords1.latitude) * cos(deltaLon);
    deg = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(y, x));

    if(deg < 0)
    {
        deg = -deg;
    }
    else
    {
        deg = 360 - deg;
    }

    return deg;
}
```

Is this the correct way to calculate my angle with another location? Or am I missing a step? Being the arrow points directly in the opposite direction sometimes, my assumption is it's an issue with my math.

Comment: `trueHeading` sometimes can be negative -  "A negative value indicates that the heading could not be determined"

Answer (score 0):

To calculate radians from x & y:

```
double r = atan(y/x);
if (x<0)
    r = M_PI + r;
else if (x>0 && y<0)
    r = 2 * M_PI + r;
```

There is not issue of dividing by 0 when X is zero because the atan function handles this correctly:

> If the argument is positive infinity (negative infinity), +pi/2 (-pi/2) is returned.